# Rails: Javascript works in development but not in production environment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form in my Rails 4 app.

I have some jQuery to hide or show form fields based on selections made elsewhere in the form.

This works in development mode, but when I push to production the hidden fields are not shown when the relevant selections are made.

I have a projects form which has:

```
<%= f.input :ethics_relevance, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline, :label => 'Is a research ethics review relevant to or required for this project?' %>
                    </div>  

                        <div id="project_ethics_relevance_content" class="content hidden">

                            <div class="row">

                                <%= f.simple_fields_for :ethics do |f| %>
                                  <%= render 'ethics/ethic_fields', f: f %>
                                <% end %>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                   <%= link_to_add_association 'Add an ethics consideration', f, :ethics, partial: 'ethics/ethic_fields' %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

In my projects.js file, I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery("#project_ethics_relevance").on('click', function() {
      if (jQuery(this)[0].checked) {
          jQuery('#project_ethics_relevance_content').removeClass('hidden');
      } else {
          jQuery('#project_ethics_relevance_content').addClass('hidden');
      }
   });

});
```

In development, when the :ethics_relevance boolean is true, the form fields for ethics_fields are displayed.

In production, I check the box, but the form fields do not display. I don't have any related console errors showing in my code inspector.

Can anyone see what might need to be done to get javascript files to work in production mode?

Comment: Can you try putting a console.log("here I am ") in your code to see if it is actually firing?  Do you have sprockets?  Are you precompiling your assets? where is your app deployed?

Comment: Do you mean I should push the production version with that log entry in it? How could it work in development mode and not in production mode? I'll give it a try.

Comment: @ruby_newbie I'm not sure if I got the gist of what you mean, but I added the line: console.log("here i am") beneath the boolean question. It prints out as text on the form page. I can't see anything from doing that that helps me understand why I did that.

Comment: Is the js code included in your compiled js file?

Comment: What i meant is in your JS put a log statement under "jQuery("#project_ethics_relevance").on('click', function() ".  Then click on the element that you expect to fire your jQuery and look in the console(in developer tools) to see if your statement is being logged.  Since your jQuery is basically style related there is a chance that the code is running but you are not seeing the functionality because some other styles are over-ridding it.  If you see your statement logging then you know your jQuery is firing.  IF you don't see it you know it isn't firing.

Comment: @dan-klasson - how do I check if its in my compiled js file. Its in a file called projects.js saved in my app/assets/javascripts folder - i think that means that it is compiled??

Comment: @ruby_newbie - I tried this and pushed to production. When I inspect the element tab - I can't see 'here i am'. In the element tab, I can see the container for the hidden fields. It doesnt appear on screen though. In the console tab, there are no js errors.

Comment: Do you have sprockets? Are you precompiling your assets? where is your app deployed?

Comment: @ruby_newbie - I do have sprockets. It's on heroku. Yes - I precompiled assets in the production environment with this command: RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile

Comment: @ruby_newbie here i am displays in the console inspector when I run local host, but it does not when I push and try in production mode

Comment: Are the Ids and or classes as you would expect on the fields?  Is it possible you don't have jQuery in your production environment or do you use it throughout the project?

Comment: @ruby_newbie I use jQuery throughout the project. The classes all look ok to me.